# force trigger hover on each element in list by timeout if cursor stopped move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple menu navigation list like ul>li*5>a and simple hover effects on li.
I want to make onload page if user dont moving cursor n-seconds, script starts to force hover on each li each n-second and repeating around. What is the best realization of it?

Comment: Add your code. Did you try something?

Comment: Also, what is your native language? Maybe communication in your mother tongue would be more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, this is one way of doing it...

```js
(function() {
  let cycleStarted;
  let mouseLastMoved = 0;
  
  // add a handler to detect mouse movement
  $(window).on('mousemove', () => {
    window.clearTimeout(cycleStarted);
    cycleStarted = false;
    $('.hover').get().forEach((li) => {
      // clear the currently hovered item
      // and apparently .removeClass is also borked
      // hence, doing it this way.
      li.classList.remove('hover');
    });
    mouseLastMoved = (new Date()).getTime();
  });
  
  const cycleMenuItemHover = () => {
    const items = $('.menu li').get();
    // doing this by hand as jQuery.index is clearly borked and cannot be trusted
    const hovered = items.filter((li) => { // get the element that is hovered
      return li.classList.contains('hover')
    });
    const current = items.indexOf(hovered[0]); // get its index in the list of all items
    if (hovered.length) {
      // one was hovered, unhover it
      hovered[0].classList.remove('hover');
    }
    let next = 0; // default for no current hover, or for last item hovered
    if (current > -1 && current < (items.length - 1)) {
      next = current + 1; // set it to the next one
    }
    // hover the next one
    items[next].classList.add('hover');
    // do this again in 1s
    cycleStarted = window.setTimeout(cycleMenuItemHover, 1000);
  }
  
  let checkMovement = window.setInterval(() => {
    const now = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (!cycleStarted && now > (mouseLastMoved + 5000)) {
      cycleStarted = window.setTimeout(cycleMenuItemHover, 1000);
    }
  }, 5000);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
.menu, .menu li {
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.menu > ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.menu li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.hover { background-color: #BBB;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
    <li>Menu Item 4</li>
    <li>Menu Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```